# Split Database into multi tenant database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, database-migration

We've a large DB (around 5GB). now, we're planning to split this DB into multi tenant DB. what's the best way to migrate this databse into multi tenant by retaining all constraints? I'm using MySQL

Please help

Comment: What problem are you having, what database platform are you using right now? I assume you want to stick with it.

Comment: I'm using MYSQL and want to stick with it. All I want is, split single db into multiple dbs by retaining all constraints.

Comment: Can you edit your question and tag MySql and add your requirements. But I still don't think it's really enough detail for a valid question